# GoDaddy cpanel install: Trying to install Drush for Drupal and possibly can't find php-cli?

Tags: linux, bash, drupal, drush

*Disclaimer: My cli and linux knowledge is not the best*

This is a pretty fresh cpanel install. I am trying to follow this instructional: [Godady Link](https://www.godaddy.com/help/how-to-install-drush-on-cpanel-shared-hosting-12396)

I get an error when I get to the step where you input the following:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

-bash: /usr/local/php5/bin/php: No such file or directory
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 16133)

I tried to proceed anyhow. I get another error at the end when I try to input the following:

```
drush help
```

/home//drush/drush: line 125: /usr/local/php5/bin/php: No such file or directory
/home//drush/drush: line 125: exec: /usr/local/php5/bin/php: cannot execute: No such file or directory

Even when I try to enter the command php, I get:

/usr/local/php5/bin/php: No such file or directory

I am not really sure if php is really missing,but it looks like that to the untrained eye...and if it is, I don't know how to proceed to install it and get this stuff working.

Forgive me if this is a simple question or has already been answered. I tried extensive searches and came up with nothing useful.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment due to rep.  You can check if a program is installed by typing `which <program>` or `whereis <program>`.  We also need to know which version of linux you are running.

To install Curl on Debian/Ubuntu: `sudo apt install curl`
PHP usually comes installed on linux, and there are different versions.  It might be that you have the wrong version of PHP installed.

[Here is a post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/756181/installing-php-5-6-on-xenial-16-04) explaining how to purge PHP and then reinstall v 5.6 on Ubuntu.